# Hide face docs in x-ray edit-mode face-selection

Tags: edit-mode

I have a mesh with millions of faces and vertices. In edit-mode with x-ray enabled, in face-selection mode, the face dots make it very hard to see the mesh (and its materials). Is there a way to hide the face dots?

[image]

As mentioned in the commends, the face dots can be made smaller in *Edit* > *Preferences* > *Themes* > *3D Viewport* > *Face Dot Size*, but that's not enough.

Comment: Can you share a picture? You can also change the vertex size under *Edit > Preferences > Themes > 3D Viewport > Vertex Size*

Comment: In face selection mode you shouldn't see any vertex dots. As @HarryMcKenzie says please include an image in your question. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie thanks, that helps but doesn't solve my issue. I've added a screenshot to the question

Comment: @JohnEason you're right, what I was seeing was face dots. I've update the question

Comment: @EpicWink no you cannot hide the dots. they will forever be there. https://blenderartists.org/t/remove-vertexs-dots-on-faces-in-editmode/632140/5 the issue is that you have way too many faces, try to decimate your model with the Decimate modifier.